# Javascript ticker in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ticker

How to create a simple ticker in asp.net which runs horizontal at the bottom of the aspx page. 
I want it to simple because I want to put it on the production site and I can't compile the code again.

Comment: Was it so hard to search for it in Google/Bing? :)

Comment: @Shoban I tried the same but all I am getting is messy code on which I am not sure that they don't harm my production site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mioplanet.com/rsc/newsticker_javascript.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link but as this is the professional site for my client, I can't use that control which gives the link to this site. it is a free control but with a site link